# Start activity in another activity in Android

Tags: java, android

After press SignUp button, Display error : unfortunately app has stopped

LogCat error :     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lolacupcakes/com.example.lolacupcakes.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

SignUpActivity: Java Code

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText emailId, password;
    Button btnSignUp;
    TextView tvSignIn;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        emailId = findViewById(R.id.emailIDSignUp);
        password = findViewById(R.id.pwdIDSignUp);
        btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnIDSignUp);
        tvSignIn = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = emailId.getText().toString();
                String pwd = password.getText().toString();

                if(email.isEmpty())
                {
                    emailId.setError("Please Enter Email Id");
                    emailId.requestFocus();
                }
                else if (pwd.isEmpty())
                {
                    password.setError("Please Enter Email Id");
                    password.requestFocus();
                }
                else if (email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Fields are Empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (!(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty()))
                {
                    mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pwd).addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "SignUp Unsuccessful, Please Try Again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Error Occurred!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
        tvSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

SignUpActivity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SignUpActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnIDSignUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
        android:text="Sign Up" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_lola" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pwdIDSignUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="206dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailIDSignUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="269dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="87dp"
        android:text="Already have an account? Sign in here." />


</RelativeLayout>
```

HomeActivity  Java Code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnlogout;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;

    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        btnlogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intoMain  = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
                startActivity(intoMain);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

HomeActivityXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Logout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="424dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You never assign a value to `btnlogout` in `HomeActivity`, so it is `null`. After `setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);`, call `findViewById()` to retrieve the widget from the inflated layout and assign it to `btnlogout`. You already have similar code for this in `SignUpActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed initializing `btnlogout`. Add this line in `HomeActivity` `onCreate` before setting `View.OnClickListener`

```
btnlogout = findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create btnSignUp object before setonlicklistener for button
     btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

Answer (score -1):

You need to create the btnSignUp object before setonclicklistener.

Comment: Please try not to answer with one-liners, those tend to not be very helpful. Ideally you'd explain your solution in more detail and optionally post some example code to go with it. As it is, your answer is quite vague and not very helpful.